# CAML Query - Results

Tags: 2010, caml-query

I've got a mad issue. I'm doing a `caml` query on a couple of lists. 
When I make the query with querying the `contenttype` I get 2 results. If I remove the `contenttype` from the query, it returns no results. How can that?
Please see both queries:

**with contenttype:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Invalid' />
                <Value Type='Boolean'>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='SupplierPGProduct' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>
                        <![CDATA[414 - Organic Pigments - Toyo Ink]]>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>
                            <![CDATA[fiber]]>
                        </Value>
                    </Contains>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
                        <Value Type='Computed'>
                            <![CDATA[fiber]]>
                        </Value>
                    </Contains>
                </Or>
            </And>
        </And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>
                <![CDATA[Brochure]]>
            </Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**Result:** 2 items

**without contenttype:**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Invalid' />
                <Value Type='Boolean'>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='SupplierPGProduct' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>
                        <![CDATA[414 - Organic Pigments - Toyo Ink]]>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>
                        <![CDATA[fiber]]>
                    </Value>
                </Contains>
            </And>
        </And>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>
                <![CDATA[fiber]]>
            </Value>
        </Contains>
    </And>
</Where>
```

**Result:** 0 items

Anybody an idea or a hint for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second query the condition Linkfilename contains fiber is implemented differently. I tried to break down each query

**Query 1**:

```
(
  ( Invalid="0" AND 
         ( SupplierPGProduct="Organic Pigments - Toyo Ink" AND 
              ( Title="Fiber" OR LinkFileName contains "Fiber" ) 
         ) 
   ) AND 
   ContentType="Brochure"
)
```

**Query 2:**

```
( 
   ( Invalid = "0" AND 
       ( SuplierPGProduct="Oranic Pigment - Tokyo Ink" AND Title contains "Fiber" ) 
   ) AND 
   LinkFileName contains "fiber" 
)
```

If you want to remove contentType condition from the first query it would look like below

```
<Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Invalid' />
                <Value Type='Boolean'>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='SupplierPGProduct' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>
                        <![CDATA[414 - Organic Pigments - Toyo Ink]]>
                    </Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>
                            <![CDATA[fiber]]>
                        </Value>
                    </Contains>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
                        <Value Type='Computed'>
                            <![CDATA[fiber]]>
                        </Value>
                    </Contains>
                </Or>
            </And>
        </And>
</Where>
```